# Getting exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke'

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have been playing with Jenkins pipeline (*i.e.* using a `Jenkinsfile`) for a while, but unfortunately I've reached a dead end.

### Notes:

**Using 'GitHub Organization' folder to build PullRequests.**

**The 'sanjer' node is a virtual machine sitting inside the Jenkins machine as a slave. For some reason jenkins doesnt seem to find it, the node is online and functioning just fine.**

The pipeline fails on the sanjer node stages

The Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:282)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:95)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.WorkspaceStepExecution.start(WorkspaceStepExecution.java:62)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:52)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:103)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:60)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is the Jenkinsfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import groovy.util.*

sanjer_ip = "10.0.0.0"
work_dir = '/opt/tikal'
deploy_dir = "${work_dir}/deploy"

properties properties: [
  disableConcurrentBuilds()
]
node ("localroot"){
    ws ("${work_dir}") {
        stage('init'){
            checkout scm
            sh "cd ${deploy_dir}; ./deploy.sh init"
            sh "/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE"
        }
     }
}

node ("sanjer"){
    ws ("${work_dir}")
        stage('reqs-sanjer'){
            sh "cd ${deploy_dir}; ./deploy.sh init"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Latter node block is missing curly brackets `{ }` to start `ws` block and to close `stage` block. It should be:

```
node ("sanjer"){
    ws ("${work_dir}"){
        stage('reqs-sanjer'){
            sh "cd ${deploy_dir}; ./deploy.sh init"
        }
    }
}
```

Such huge error message looks like there was bigger problem, indeed.

Comment: Thanks! (better late then never.. )